# how can i pass the session value and put it in textboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, session-variables

here is my login button click code. i have set the session["Username"] to the input of the customer in txtUser.text.

```
protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPassword = "select Password from UserData where Username ='" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
            string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
            if (password == txtPassword.Text)
            {
                Session["Username"] = txtUser.Text;
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Record saved successfully')</script>");
                Response.Redirect("OrderNow.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
            }
```

and here is where i call it. (ordernow.aspx) this is where the customer is redirected when he/she places and order. im planning to pass the values of the customer (email address username phone number) into the textboxes before submitting the order.

```
private void GetMyCart()
    {
        DataTable dtProducts; // declare data table = dtProducts.
        if (Session["MyCart"] != null) // check whether session is null or not.
        {
            dtProducts = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"]; //if session is not null, assign all session to dtproducts.
        }
        else
        {
            dtProducts = new DataTable(); //if session is null, create new datatable (dtproducts).
        }
        if (dtProducts.Rows.Count > 0) // if rows.count is greater than 0, it means there is a value records from the session.
        { 
            txtCustomerName.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
            //txtCustomerPhoneNo.Text = Session["Contact"].ToString();
            //txtCustomerEmailID.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();
            //txtCustomerAddress.Text = Session["DeliveryAddress"].ToString();
            txtTotalProducts.Text = dtProducts.Rows.Count.ToString(); // this will display all of the chosen records
            btnIslandGas.Text = dtProducts.Rows.Count.ToString();
            dlCartProducts.DataSource = dtProducts;
            dlCartProducts.DataBind();
            UpdateTotalBill();

            pnlMyCart.Visible = true;
            pnlCheckOut.Visible = true;
            pnlEmptyCart.Visible = false;
            pnlCategories.Visible = false;
            pnlProducts.Visible = false;
            pnlOrderPlaceSuccessfully.Visible = false;

        }
        else // session is empty
        {
            pnlEmptyCart.Visible = true; // since session is empty and there is no value record, pull up the empty shopping cart page
            pnlMyCart.Visible = false;
            pnlCheckOut.Visible = false;
            pnlCategories.Visible = false;
            pnlProducts.Visible = false;
            pnlOrderPlaceSuccessfully.Visible = false;

            dlCartProducts.DataSource = null;
            dlCartProducts.DataBind();
            txtTotalProducts.Text = "0"; // total products, price and number logo is set to 0.
            txtTotalPrice.Text = "0";
            btnIslandGas.Text = "0";
        }
```

the Session["Username"] is working. meaning it is binded with the txtCustomername.text. but the rest are not working (email,address,phone no.)

Comment: It should work if you have set `Session` values properly.

Comment: Before you assign them to your textboxes, you should have already set them like `Session["Firstname"] = "some first name"`

Comment: Where do you bind them, are you doing it in pageload?

Comment: where will i set the session values?

Comment: its not in the page load. it is when customers click on the place order button then im planning to have their information autocamtically seen inisde the textboxes. like their name, address, email before submitting the order.

Comment: Generally, if the customer logs in, you should set the Session values then and there itself and if he/she is directly purchasing without logging in, then you will not have these values and you will have to let them type. As simple as that.

Comment: actually the session variables are based on the customer input. i mangaged to make 1 textbox work. my code is: Session["Username"] = txtUser.Text; this line of code is in my log in page. i tried to make the same code in my registration page where i get the user input and store as a session but is not working.

Comment: How do you store the user input into session on the registration page?
on some button click or what ?

Comment: i tried this code but seems not working : scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Session["Contact"]= txtContact.Text;
                Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
                Session["DeliveryAddress"] = txtAddress.Text;
                label_register_success.Text = ("Registration Successful!");

Comment: and i have these codes for my registration page as well: scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFN.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLN.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPW.Text);
                scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryAddress", txtAddress.Text);

Comment: both codes i provided(session and scm.pamaeters.addwithvalue) are inside registration_button_click

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod edit you question and post the code there. post whole resiter button click code

Comment: ok now add how you access these session values in Home.aspx . add code with full containing method

Comment: the way you set them is fine, btw you should make the re-direction to home.aspx after closing the connection, ie.
            conn.Close(); first and then redirection

Comment: check my new question sir @tariq

Comment: ok, do you get any error message?

Comment: no error message sir @tariq but its not redirected to the ordernow.aspx page. but when i comment out the email,phone,address session, its working fine with the session[username]

Comment: Didn't the answer help ? @PaoloDuhaylungsod

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, what you are doing is that on your login page in case the user is authenticated i.e in your code when the passwords are successfully matched. The Session variables viz. Contact, Email, DeliveryAddress are not set at all. Only Name is set.

After this you make redirection to ordernow.aspx page. Hence you don't get them there. You only get one you set.

In register page you set the other Session variables but you have to understand that it's only after that they will be available in ordernow.aspx

So if you go from register to ordernow.aspx you will get the values but not when you go from login page to ordernow.aspx

You need to set the other Session variables as well in the Login  page before making redirection to the ordernow page and accessing them there.

**Update:**

You are only getting password from the database on the basis of the username, but instead you need to get the whole user record with other details like email, contact , address as well. Then match the password, if it matches you have your user and all his other details with which you need to set Session variables.

**Update Second:**

```
if (temp == 1)
{
   conn.Open();
   string checkPassword = "select * from UserData where Username ='" + txtUser.Text + "'";
   SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
   using (SqlDataReader oReader = passCom.ExecuteReader())
   {
      while (oReader.Read())
      {
        if(oReader["UserName"].ToString().Replace(" ", "") == txtPassword.Text.Trim())
        {
           Session["Username"]  = oReader["FirstName"].ToString();
           Session["Contact"]  = oReader["Contact"].ToString(); 
           Session["Email"] = oReader["Email"].ToString();
           Session["DeliveryAddress"] = oReader["DeliveryAddress"].ToString();
           Response.Redirect("OrderNow.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
           lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
           break;
        }                      
      }
      myConnection.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: i really get your point. but in the log in page, how can i set the variables there knowing that only username and password are being gathered from the user?

Comment: can you give me a sample? based on our conversation? please

Comment: i understand. but how can i do that? actually thats what i have in mind but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod for that you need to tell us how you maintain data in the database i.e what table and what columns it has.

Comment: database is stored in sql sir @tariq. select*from UserData. columns are ID(PK) Firstname,LastName,Email,Password,deliveryAddress,ZipCode,ContactNumber

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod , check now